# Android - Missing Application Subclass

Tags: java, android, adt, google-play, classnotfoundexception

I'm slightly confused, and more than a bit annoyed at an issue I've been having with Eclipse , ADT, and Google Play.

I'm running OS X 10.8.2, Eclipse 4.2.1, and ADT 20.0.3.

Following is the workflow that is causing the issue:

- Developer Alpha is in charge of building the Android app for internal / external release.
- Other Developers work on app, push changes to GitHub.
- Developer Alpha does standard pull / mergetool, etc
- Alpha opens up Eclipse, refreshes the main project, and two library projects (ActionBarSherlock and FacebookSdk)
- Alpha runs a Project > Clean > All
- Running at this point creates an application that works fine in both the simulator as well as hardware, ranging from OS 2.3.3 up to 4.0.1
- Alpha runs Android Tools > Export Signed APK, puts in the key passes, etc.
- The resulting build is emailed to people, or uploaded to Google. Note that it's running the EXACT same code that just ran in the simulator / hardware post-merge.
- The following occurs, SOMETIMES:

Trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.COMPANY.android.APPLICATION.application.APPLICATIONApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.COMPANY.android.APPLICATION.application.APPLICATIONApplication
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4089)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.OO4usa.android.fanzlive.application.FanzliveApplication
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
    ... 11 more
```

Now, my question is, why is the Application subclass not packaged / visible?

To make matters worse, we're using Acra, and the annotation to catch a crash is on the missing Application, so, no crash reports.

Lastly, I figure that we can always try testing the built APK, by running:

```
adb install ~/path/to/app.apk
```

but, will this verifiably be the same binary that a user will get after they download it from the Play store? Will Google mess with the build or its metadata at all?

**EDIT:** *The relevant bit of the manifest*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.COMPANY.android.APPLICATION"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.3.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.APPLICATIONApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.APP_green" >

        <!-- activities -->

        <!-- snip -->

        <!-- services -->

        <!-- snip -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT:** *Auto-generated proguard.cfg*

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: could your attach your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @Hit: Done, although it's worth noting that this isn't a new app, it's just a new version (6 broke on Play, I just re-submitted 7). That and the `versionName` are the only thing that changed in the Manifest.

Comment: do you use Proguard or some other obfuscator?

Comment: @Hit: Not intentionally, but there is an auto-generated one in the Project's root, I've updated my question to have it.

Comment: IMHO this: `.application.APPLICATIONApplication` seems so wrong ^^

Comment: @shkschneider: I'm not sure what you mean. If you're referring to the naming, COMPANY and APPLICATION are not literally those strings, they're obfuscating my company and their particular app. If my app was Poker, it'd be .application.PokerApplication. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: Difference in debug build in Eclipse and "Export Signed APK" - last one obfuscate your code, using rules from `proguard.cfg`. So, your problem should be in this config. Are you sure that sometimes production build, builded by "Export Signed APK" are working just fine, but sometimes not?

Comment: @Hit: Yes, positive. Last night I built and submitted to Play, got an email from a client today that it crashes on open. Did NOTHING to the code, other than upping the versionName/Code, and submitted a new build, and it works just fine, same device, etc.

Comment: Can you test previous build, that was crashing, on your Android device or emulator? Is it crashing?

Comment: @Hit: Good call. Running: `adb uninstall com.COMPANY.android.APPLICATION` then `adb install ~/COMPANY/Repos/APPLICATION/build/2012-10-28_02_CODENAME.apk` installs the .APK just fine, and it crashes on start. So, that at least rules Google meddling out of the equation. It looks to definitely be a signing / exporting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Our project just had a similar problem.  Release build in Eclipse was discarding classes left and right.

For some reason, when a **debug** build was first done (all the way to running it on an emulator), and **then** a release export was done it started working.

This sounds to me like a bug in Eclipse, since proguard isn't even configured for use in our `project.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

> will this verifiably be the same binary that a user will get after
>   they download it from the Play store? Will Google mess with the build
>   or its metadata at all?

No, users will get **exactly** the **same** `.apk` file that you will upload to your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home).

Regarding specified exception - it tell you that `Application` subclass, specified in `android:name` attribute of `<application>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` is missing in final '.apk' file. This exception should be thrown **every** time you try to run specific build of your app, rather than "sometimes".

Comment: I don't quite follow. It is my understanding that I'm allowed to omit the first parts of the package as long as they're common. My package goes `com.COMPANY.android.APPLICATION`, then goes into `.activity`, `.provider`, etc. So, defining the application as `.application.APPLICATIONApplication` shouldn't be an issue. Furthermore, this setup has been working for almost a year now, across 6 versions of the application. And, the code will run just fine when ran from Eclipse. It seems to be constrained entirely, randomly, to building a signed APK.

Comment: Additionally, as my posted excerpt shows, I am defining my `package` in my `manifest`, so all of the paths, when concatenated, as according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) document, are correct.

Comment: You are correct that you can just use ".subpackage.ClassName" as the Application class name. But I too am having the exact same problem, except it happens with Eclipse too. The Android builder is simply not including big chunks of the application classes, for some reason. Did you get a solution that works?

Comment: Sorry, my problem was a corrupted .classpath file; the output was being put in the wrong directory, not really ADT's fault :-) But it's one more thing to check if you're having similar problems.